# $ \exists L>0, \forall m,n\in\mathbb{N}, \forall A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}, \|\sqrt{AA^T}-\sqrt{BB^T}\| \le L \|A-B\|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

Is it true that
\begin{equation}
\exists L>0, \forall m,n\in\mathbb{N}, \forall A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}, \|\sqrt{AA^T}-\sqrt{BB^T}\| \le L \|A-B\|,
\end{equation}
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm with respect to Euclidean norms in the domain and in the codomain?

If not, is it true that
\begin{equation}
\forall m,n\in\mathbb{N}, \exists L>0, \forall A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}, \|\sqrt{AA^T}-\sqrt{BB^T}\| \le L \|A-B\|?
\end{equation}

If $m = 1 = n$, the previous inequality holds trivially with $L =1$, since for each $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\|\sqrt{AA^T}-\sqrt{BB^T}\|= |\sqrt{A^2}-\sqrt{B^2}| = \big||A|-|B|\big| \le |A-B| = \|A-B\|.
\end{equation*}
If $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, we can use:

- $\forall A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}, \|AA^T-B B^T\| \le \big(\|A\|+\|B\|\big) \|A-B\|$
- $\forall A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, \big((A^T = A) \land (B^T = B) \land (A,B\succeq0)\big) \implies\big(\lambda_{\operatorname{min}}(\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{B})\|\sqrt A- \sqrt B\| \le \|A-B\|\big)$

to get for example that, for $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ such that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n=\operatorname{rank}(B)$, it holds
\begin{equation*}
\|\sqrt{AA^T}-\sqrt{BB^T}\| \le \frac{\sigma_{\operatorname{max}}(A)+\sigma_{\operatorname{max}}(B)}{\sigma_{\operatorname{min}}(A)+\sigma_{\operatorname{min}}(B)} \|A-B\|,
\end{equation*}
where $\lambda_{\operatorname{min}}(\cdot)$ is the minimum eigenvalue, $\sigma_{\operatorname{max}}(\cdot)$ is the maximum singular value and $\sigma_{\operatorname{min}}(\cdot)$ is the minimum singular value.

However, this inequality seems somewhat underwhelming, at least compared to the one we have in the $1$-dimensional case (i.e., the triangle inequality), where $A \mapsto \sqrt{AA^T}$ is globally $1$-Lipschitz. Can we do better in the general case?

Comment: Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis* has some relevant results. For arbitrary unitarily invariant norms (including the spectral norm), excercise VII.5.3 asks you to derive the inequality
$$
\|\sqrt{AA^T} - \sqrt{BB^T}\| \leq \left(1 + \frac{2\min\{\sigma_\max(A) + \sigma_\max(B)\}}{\sigma_{\min}(A) + \sigma_\min(B)}\right)\|A - B\|,
$$
which is marginally tighter than your bound I believe

Comment: For the *Frobenius* norm, he gives the following results. If $A$ and $B$ are normal, we have
$$
\|\sqrt{AA^T} - \sqrt{BB^T}\|_F \leq \|A - B\|_F.
$$
More generally, we have
$$
\|\sqrt{AA^T} - \sqrt{BB^T}\|_F^2 + \|\sqrt{A^TA} - \sqrt{B^TB}\|_F^2 \leq 2\|A-B\|_F^2,
$$
from which it follows that
$$
\|\sqrt{AA^T} - \sqrt{BB^T}\|_F \leq \sqrt{2}\|A - B\|_F.
$$
He also shows that $\sqrt{2}$ is the lowest coefficient that works in this equation (i.e. as a global Lipschitz constant).

Comment: Quick correction: that first inequality should read
$$
\|\sqrt{AA^T} - \sqrt{BB^T}\| \leq \left(1 + \frac{2\min\{\sigma_\max(A),\sigma_\max(B)\}}{\sigma_{\min}(A) + \sigma_\min(B)}\right)\|A - B\|,
$$

Comment: So, if $AA^*=A^*A$ and $B^*B = B B^*$ (in particular, $m=n$), we have that $\|\sqrt{AA^T} - \sqrt{BB^T}\| \le \|\sqrt{AA^T} - \sqrt{BB^T}\|_F \le \sqrt{2} \|A-B\|_F \le  \sqrt{2n} \|A-B\|$, right?

Comment: Good point! Actually for the inequality that you're using here, there is no requirement that $AA^* = A^*A$ (hence the "more generally"), nor is there a requirement that the matrices are square. We get the completely general statement that $\|\sqrt{AA^T} - \sqrt{BB^T}\| \leq \sqrt{2\min\{m,n\}}\|A-B\|$